# Why does `docker-compose up` erase volumes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm testing lots of services as containers, usually through docker-compose.

Since I'm new to docker this question can appear noobish, anyway.

At some point I had a docker-compose stack (few containers with volumes) running. I had to stop containers to re-use the same ports; I did that with `docker stop` command.

When I was ready to start my containers again I did:

```
$ docker-compose start
Starting jenkins   ... done
Starting gitlab-ce ... done
ERROR: No containers to start
```

I checked for containers and was surprised to see this:

```
$ docker-compose ps
Name   Command   State   Ports
------------------------------
```

So I ran:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating volume "dockerpipelinejenkins_jenkins_home" with default driver
Creating volume "dockerpipelinejenkins_gitlab_logs" with default driver
Creating volume "dockerpipelinejenkins_gitlab_data" with default driver
Creating volume "dockerpipelinejenkins_gitlab_config" with default driver
Creating dockerpipelinejenkins_jenkins_1   ... done
Creating dockerpipelinejenkins_gitlab-ce_1 ... done
Attaching to dockerpipelinejenkins_jenkins_1, dockerpipelinejenkins_gitlab-ce_1
```

... and I was shocked to see that my volumes had been recreated, effectively erasing my data.

Why did docker compose erase the volumes, and will it happen every time when I stop docker containers using `docker stop`?

Comment: `docker stop` should not be erasing volumes. After running `docker stop`, run `docker ps -a`. Are your containers still showing up then?

Comment: yes, although when I was browesing the volumes `ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/dockerpipeline_gitlab_config/_data` the data was gone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `stop` will not remove volumes. In fact it cannot since the container would still exist and therefore holding the volume as in use:

```
$ docker run --name test-vol -v test-vol:/data busybox sleep 10

$ docker volume rm test-vol
Error response from daemon: unable to remove volume: remove test-vol: volume is in use - [1de0add7a8dd6e083326888bc02d9954bfc7b889310ac238c34ac0a5b2f16fbf]
```

A `docker-compose down` will remove the containers, but it will not remove the volumes unless you explicitly pass that option:

```
$ docker-compose down --help
Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images
created by `up`.

By default, the only things removed are:

- Containers for services defined in the Compose file
- Networks defined in the `networks` section of the Compose file
- The default network, if one is used

Networks and volumes defined as `external` are never removed.

Usage: down [options]

Options:
    --rmi type          Remove images. Type must be one of:
                        'all': Remove all images used by any service.
                        'local': Remove only images that don't have a custom tag
                        set by the `image` field.
    -v, --volumes       Remove named volumes declared in the `volumes` section
                        of the Compose file and anonymous volumes
                        attached to containers.
    --remove-orphans    Remove containers for services not defined in the
                        Compose file
```

If you have stopped all running containers, and also run a prune, and pass the option to that prune to also delete volumes, then that would remove the volumes:

```
$ docker system prune --help

Usage:  docker system prune [OPTIONS]

Remove unused data

Options:
  -a, --all             Remove all unused images not just dangling ones
      --filter filter   Provide filter values (e.g. 'label=<key>=<value>')
  -f, --force           Do not prompt for confirmation
      --volumes         Prune volumes
```

In short, what you have described is not the default behavior of docker, and you have run some command to remove these volumes that was not included in the question.

Comment: After your answer I did checked the volumes more carefully and found that the new volumes and missing volumes had almost the same names. pheew I though that my data was all gone.